# Program not printing

Tags: python

I wrote this program but it is not executing when I print it:

```
 age= int(input("How old is your dog?"))

      if age>0:
   
           print("Please input positive number")

      elif age<=2:
    
           dage= age*10.5

      else age>2:
   
           dage=21+((age-2)*4)

      print("The dog is", dage, "years old")

print(age)
```

What am I missing to make it run?

Comment: `else age>2:` is a syntax error - and the indentation is also incorrect, which is another syntax error. These should have been pointed out to you by Python when you tried to run your code.

Comment: `if age > 0`, age already _is_ a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to unindent the conditional statements. I think your conditional statements also need some work -- I've updated it a bit. See below.

Try

```py
age = int(input("How old is your dog?" ))
dage = 0

if age < 0:
    print("Please input positive number")
elif age <= 2:
    dage = age*10.5
else:
    dage = 21+((age-2)*4)

print("The dog is", dage, "years old")

print("age", age)
```